# An example of using LibSVM in java

Tags: java, svm, libsvm

I am considering using libsvm. Currently, I have transformed my feature vectors to SVM feature vectors format. I am using LibSVM inside a project I will need to somehow use it within my app. The problem is that at the moment all examples available use the command line to provide input to the LibSVM. I don want this.
Can you please give me an example of how I can use it within my code (no calls to the command prompt and no Weka).
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applet doesn't use command-line input. Check `libsvm-3.11.tar.gz\libsvm-3.11.tar\libsvm-3.11\java`

Answer (score 4):

There are examples in the distribution source code https://github.com/arnaudsj/libsvm/tree/master/java

Comment: The URL above is an unofficial snapshot distribution mirror. I suggest you get the updated source from http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/ instead.